# Excluding null results and counting number of rows based on several elements

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have the tables 'template' and 'object' at a relationship one to many.
I need to know how many 'objects' share the same 'template'.

This is simple enough but there are two columns in the object table, 'theme' and 'active'.

I need to add to my query to return the count of:

- How many objects share the same template.
- and have different 'object.active's (active is boolean, and is never null)
- (so if there are three 'object's sharing the same 'template' then the count will not be incremented)
- and have different object.theme's ('theme' is varchar and can be null)
- 'theme' will only have a value if object.active is true
- excluding null object.themes

My biggest problem is that if 'object.active' all have the same value '1' or '0' then it should not add to the count, but if they all have the same value '1' and each have different object.theme's then they do need to add to the count.

So far I am at the following but when going through manually and counting what the figure should be I get an incorrect result:

```
  SELECT sum(tmpUse) FROM(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS tmpUse,tmp.title FROM templates tmp
    LEFT JOIN assessmentinstances ai ON ai.template_id = tmp.id
    GROUP BY tmp.id
    HAVING tmpUse>1
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT ai.data_theme)>1 
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT ai.mobile_ready)>1
  ) alias


template table
    _____
   | id  |
    -----
   |  1  |
   |  2  |
   |  3  |
   |  4  |
   |  5  |
    -----

object table
    ____________________________________
   | id  | template_id | active |  theme |
   |-----|-------------|--------|--------|
   |  a  |      1      |   0    |   null |
   |  b  |      1      |   1    |    x   |
   |  c  |      1      |   1    |    y   |
   |  d  |      3      |   1    |    x   |
   |  e  |      3      |   0    |   null |
   |  f  |      1      |   1    |    z   |
   |  g  |      2      |   1    |    z   |
   |  h  |      2      |   0    |   null |
   |  i  |      4      |   1    |    y   |
   |  j  |      5      |   1    |    z   |
   |  k  |      1      |   1    |    x   |
   |  l  |      1      |   0    |   null |
   |  m  |      1      |   0    |   null |
   |  n  |      3      |   0    |   null |
   |  o  |      3      |   1    |    x   |
   |-------------------------------------|
```

The result I would hope from these tables would be:

```
id count
 1 3
 2 1
 3 1
 4 0
 5 0

 = 5
```

- Template id 1 has 7 objects, objects include both 0 and 1 actives so look at the themes. the themes associated are the followinf: null, x, y, z, x, null, null. We ignore nulls and duplicates so this would add 3 to the count.
- Template id 2 has 2 objects, one is active 1 and one 0, because these are different but only one distinct theme we can add 1 to the count.
- Template id 3 has 2 active 1's and two active 0's so we know at least one will be added to the count. looking at their themes, they are the same so no more to the count, so only 1 is added for template id 3.
- Template id 4 and 5 both have one object so we know this will not add to the count.

so the output from the query will be:

**'5'**

Comment: Can you give example with table structure and its value.and what will be your output according to that

Comment: @CharveeShah added, I hope this make more sense, it is a real mouthful for me

Comment: Is 'e,a,g' correct - or should it be 'e,f,g'? If it IS correct then what's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, slippy fingers. it should be efg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
select sum(themecount) from (select template.templateid,
count(distinct case when object.theme IS NOT NULL then object.theme end) themeCount
from  Object object where
count(distinct object.isActive)>1
group by object.template_id)
```

Comment: I was just writing why this wouldn't work but I think I am over thinking it. On further thought and testing, this is utterly perfect. Thank you very much Charvee

Comment: I also commend you for understanding what I was asking, I found it a very difficult question to ask robustly.